# operator _surrogate_func: no matching overload found and 2 other errors

Tags: c++

I've written a code which creates a list of buses that you can modify and manage. The whole managing process is proceed by writing strings in console. After running code I'm receiving 3 errors, none of which I understand therefore can fix. Code is planned this way:

NEW_BUS - Adds new bus in list by taking it's number, amount of stops and stop list.
ALL_BUSES - Display all buses in lexicographical order (by their name)
STOPS_FOR_BUS - Display all stops specific bus follows.
BUSES_FOR_STOP - Diplay all buses that go though the specific stop.

Here are error list:
1. operator _surrogate_func: no matching overload found
2. Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less::operator ()(_Ty 1 &&,_Ty2 &&)
3. illegal expression

All errors come from line 617 from xutility file.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>
   #include <list>
   #include <tuple>
   #include <iterator>

   using namespace std;

   class Bus {
   public:
    int StopsAmount;
    string BusNumber;
    vector<string> Stops;

    Bus(tuple<string, int, vector<string>> BusParams) {
        BusNumber = get<0>(BusParams);
        StopsAmount = get<1>(BusParams);
        Stops = get<2>(BusParams);
    }

    void ShowStops() {
        cout << BusNumber << ": ";
        for (int i = 0; i < StopsAmount; i++) cout << Stops[i] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    bool FindStop(string Stop) {
        for (int i = 0; i < StopsAmount; i++) {
            if (Stops[i] == Stop) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
            }
         };   

      class BusTraffic {
      public:
        BusTraffic() {
            while (true) {
                string Request;
                cin >> Request;
                switch (Request[0]) {
                case 'N': NEW_BUS(Request.substr(8, Request.length() - 8))      ;
                break;
            case 'B': BUSES_FOR_STOP(Request.substr(15, Request.length() - 15));
                break;
            case 'S': STOPS_FOR_BUS(Request.substr(14, Request.length() - 14));
                break;
            case 'A': ALL_BUSES();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

      private:
        list<Bus> BusList;

    void NEW_BUS(string Request) {
        BusList.push_back(Bus::Bus(SplitString(Request)));
    }

    void BUSES_FOR_STOP(string Stop) {
        cout << Stop << ": ";
        for (list<Bus>::iterator It = BusList.begin(); It != BusList.end(); It++) {
            if (It->FindStop(Stop)) {
                cout << It->BusNumber << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void STOPS_FOR_BUS(string Name) {
        cout << Name << ": ";
        for (list<Bus>::iterator It = BusList.begin(); It != BusList.end(); It++) {
            if (It->BusNumber == Name) {
                It->ShowStops();
            }
        }
    }

    void ALL_BUSES() {
        if (BusList.size() > 0) {
            BusList.sort();
            for (list<Bus>::iterator It = BusList.begin(); It != BusList.end(); It++) {
                cout << It->BusNumber << ": ";
                It->ShowStops();
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "No buses" << endl;
        }
    }

    // Converting string to information about bus
    tuple<string, int, vector<string>> &SplitString(string str) {
        tuple<string, int, vector<string>> BusParams;
        string Word = "";
        int WordNum = 0;

        for (auto Letter : str) {
            if (Letter == ' ') {
                if (WordNum == 0) get<0>(BusParams) = Word; 
                if (WordNum == 1) get<1>(BusParams) = stoi(Word);
                if (WordNum == 2) get<2>(BusParams).push_back(Word);
                Word = "";
                WordNum++;
            }
            else {
                Word = Word + Letter;
            }
        }
        get<2>(BusParams).push_back(Word);
        return BusParams;
        }
      };

      int main() {
        BusTraffic TestTraffic;
        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Even if an error message refers to something in the standard library headers, the error's cause is still going to be in your code. The error message either states where in your code directly or in a note preceding/following the error message. Please show the full error message your program generates and provide a [repro].

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you are absolutely correct. the error message here is just terrible. It's just from experience that you learn to interpret that as a missing less-than-operator.

So something in the lines of:

```
bool operator< (const Bus& lhs, const Bus& rhs) {
  // however you want to sort them...
   return (lhs.BusNumber < rhs.BusNumber);
}
```

The other small bug is within NEW_BUS: In C++ you don't need to specify the constructor name. So it's not `Bus::Bus` it's just `Bus`

Last but not least your SplitString is returning a reference to a local variable. In general that's a bad idea as that memory might simply not be accessible anymore when you try to. Just remove "&" from the return type. [Further explanations](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f43-never-directly-or-indirectly-return-a-pointer-or-a-reference-to-a-local-object).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to sort a list of buses. By the sounds of it there is no overload for the less than operator. This means C++ doesn't know how to compare objects of type bus. Add this to your Bus class and it should work. This overload of the less than operator returns true if the other bus is less than the current bus.

```
bool operator < (const Bus& otherBus) const {
   if(otherBus.StopsAmount < this.StopsAmount) {
        return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Useful links with more details:
http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/relational_operators_overloading.htm